# Plotting time separated distributions

Tags: graphics

For many reasons the following graphic is not satisfactory

```
 ϕ[t_] := N[PDF[WienerProcess[0, 1][t]]] /. {"#1" -> x, "&" -> ""}
 p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{{5, x, ϕ[1][x]}, {4, 
 x, ϕ[.5][x]}, {3, x, ϕ[.2][x]}, {2, 
 x, ϕ[.1][x]}, {1, x, ϕ[.05][x]}, {0, 
 x, ϕ[.025][x]}}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-3, 4}, {0, 3}}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False];
 p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{{5, x, 0}, {4, x, 0}, {3, x, 0}, {2, x, 0}, {1, x, 0}, {0, x, 0}}, {x, -2.5, 2}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-3, 4}, {0, 3}}, Boxed -> False, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black}];
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[{{5, -2.5, x}, {4, -2.5, x}, {3, -2.5, x}, {2, 2.5, x}, {1, -2.5, x}, {0, -2.5, x}}, {x, 0, 2},  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-3,4}, {0, 23}}, Boxed -> False,    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black}];
 a1 = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{.025, 1}}], Arrow[{{0, -3, 0}, {4, -3, 0}}, .025]}];
 a2 = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{.025, 1}}],     Arrow[{{2, 1, .65}, {2, 2, .65}}, .025]}];
 t = Graphics3D[{Text["t", {-3, -3.2, -1.25}], Text["x", {-3, 2.8, .0 .5}],   Text["t=0.025", {-2.4, 3.8, -0.5}], Text["t=0.05", {-2.4, 4, -0.78}], Text["t=0.1", {-2.4, 4.1, -1.}], Text["t=0.2", {-2.4, 4.3, -1.3}]}];
 Show[p2, p3, p1, a1, a2, t]
```

Acording to the point of view arrows an text sail in the space because they are set at absolute position,  second I would like to fill with transparency the space under the curves. Perhaps ther is a solution to have true axes...

Comment: Having the definition of `ϕ` would help as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry it was not in the same cell and I forgot to copy that one. I have edited the question to add it